# how to remove all sessionstorage whose key is some character "abc" while pages refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to remove all session value whose key is some character "abc" while pages refresh? I know how to get event when page refesh I need to remove all values in session whose key have character "abc"?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

As we store value in sessionStorage.setItem("abc","test");
thanks

Comment: we store some value in sessionstorage I need to remove that values

Comment: @DwB please check update .i need to remove all session  whose key have some character "abc"

Comment: Can I request clarity? Do you only set ("abc", "ourlargeitem"), or is it more like ("abc.userdata", "item"), ("abc.preferences", "item")?

Comment: it is like that it more like ("abc.userdata", "item"), ("abc.preferences", "item")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var key in sessionStorage) {
  if (key.indexOf("abc") === 0) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}
```

I haven't quite tested in all browsers, but iterating through in that manner seems to do the trick. This version only checks if the string begins with "abc" (-1 means it's not there, anything else would be later in the string)

Comment: Note that this will iterate over the methods of the sessionStorage object too (e.g. setItem, removeItem, clear) though that shouldn't be a problem except in some edge cases. Doing `sessionStorage.removeItem('clear')` where "clear" isn't a key returns `undefined` and does not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to get a list of all keys in HTML5 sessionStorage,
you will need to loop from 0 to sessionStorage.length - 1 and use the sessionStorage.key(index()) method to retrieve each key.

Once you have a key, it will be a string value, you must compare it to a regular expression (regex) to see if it matches the desired to-be-removed value (in your case "starts with "abc")

If a key matches the to-be-removed value,
use sessionStorage.remove(key) to remove it from session storage.

Comment: That is a nice dream.  Unfortunately, the OP claims to want to remove a subset of all keys.

Comment: can you look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702253/why-event-stoppropagation-not-working-on-switch/23702539?noredirect=1#23702539