# why event.stopPropagation(); not working on switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me why         event.stopPropagation(); not working on switch ?

I click on on click it print the row event(console) .It should print only switch console.

when I change the switch it print switch console.But when i click on click area it print row event(console). why ?
http://jsfiddle.net/k7zJ4/

```
$(function(){
$('#testSuitConfiguration').click(function () {

console.log('pp')    

});

  $( ".selectSequenc_h" ).on( "change", function(event, ui) {
        //alert('pp')
        console.log('==')
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: They're completely different event types.

Comment: so can restrict them.if i click on switch it should fire only switch fuction

Comment: If I click on row it fire only row fuction

Comment: any idea ? of this question

Comment: Tell me if you need anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pT2bU/1/

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){ 
    $(document).on('vclick','#testSuitConfiguration',function () {
        console.log('pp')    
    });
    
    $(document).on( "slidestop", ".selectSequence_h" ,function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('==');
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }); 
});
```

I have replaced your **click** event with jQuery Mobile version called **vclick**, this one don't suffer from event propagation and it works on desktop and mobile browsers.